# Export data to Excel template c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, excel, entity-framework

I have a Report Template :
[image]

I should be how to export data to Excel files same image.

Comment: Is this image that you want to export or the data that is stored somewhere in DB. Read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/151005/create-excel-xls-and-xlsx-file-from-c-sharp?rq=1

Comment: Your question would benefit from more detail. Especially on how you are generating the data for downloading.

Answer (score 0):

You should not install Excel on the server which is sometimes seen as a solution. One straightforward way is to create a download as a csv file. This will then open in Excel on the client computer. The following method shows you how to do this:

```
public ActionResult DownloadSelectedReport(int ReportID)
{
    string filename = String.Format("DownloadList{0:yyMMdd}.csv", DateTime.Today);
    MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();
    UnicodeEncoding uniEncoding = new UnicodeEncoding();
    byte[] reportString = uniEncoding.GetBytes(BuildReportAsCSV(ReportID));
    memStream.Write(reportString, 0, reportString.Length);
    return File(memStream.ToArray(), "application/vnd.ms-excel", Server.UrlEncode(filename));
}
```

Use `BuildReportAsCSV(ReportID)` to generate your report for downloading.